# CheckboxTreeViewer allow only one element to be checked

Tags: java, swt, jface

How do I force the `CheckboxTreeViewer` class to allow for only one checked element? 
I could not find a style that enforces this behavior.

The only other alternative I have to so capture the check event and uncheck the other elements

Comment: As question is voted up by other people, you can update your post with the requirement you had. i.e Why you need ONLY single element to be checked. Basically Tree viewer is used to represent hierarchical data ex: countries can have states and states can have districts etc etc. Surprisingly there is no class called **RadioTreeViewer** in SWT/JFACE where user can select single tree item.

Comment: The requirement is something like this, when the use select's the tree element, I update a table control giving details of the element. The user can select any elements to view properties. By clicking on the checkbox the user selects an item for further processing. I thought the checkbox conveys the meaning "check item for further processing" better.

Comment: @chimanrao Why did you delete your latest question?

Comment: I had written some incorrect code, the removeAll was working. After a small break and cup of tea I found my mistake! The question was incorrect, so I deleted the question.

Comment: @chimanrao If you're using a `TreeViewer`, you shouldn't manipulate the underlying `Tree`, but rather the content provider and then update the `TreeViewer`. Removing the items from the `Tree` directly may lead to unforeseen consequences...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SWT.SINGLE** AND **SWT.MULTI** style bits are related to single or multiple selection in list, tree and tables.

But AFAIK you have to use **addCheckStateListener** and deselect all elements first and then toggle the check state of current element.

Comment: Yes, I worked with the `addCheckStateListener` and deselected all selected elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
CheckboxTreeViewer treeViewer;
ICheckStateListener checkStateListener= new ICheckStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void checkStateChanged(CheckStateChangedEvent event) {
        Object checked = event.getElement();
        treeViewer.setCheckedElements(new Object[]{checked});
    }
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).